# How can I "link" a pod to a container in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I'm learning Kubernetes and I just came across a question.

I have a file for my pod, another file for my service and finally a file for my deployment.

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: site-pod
  labels:
    name: site-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: site-pod
    image: guirms/website-k8s-frontend:1.1
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 4200
```

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service
metadata:
  name: angular-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: site-pod
  ports:
  - port: 4200
    targetPort: 4200
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: site-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: site-deploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: site-deploy
```

I've just applied the pod and the service by running the command `kubectl apply my-file` and all works fine. My problem occurred when i tried to apply the deployment. The exception was:

> The Deployment "name-of-my-deploy" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers: Required value

I understand that I need to specify the containers in the deployment file, but I've created a pod precisely so I wouldn't have to pass the containers to the deployment file, because I thought like *if a need to create a file to the pod and in this file I need to pass the image that I'll use, then don't make sense to pass this container again in the deployment file*. But now that I received this error, I asked myself: *do I really need to create this pod file? I want to use one container per pod, so I'll need to specify the same container two times*. I read some articles, but not enlightening for me.

Comment: Just put it in the deployment and the pod will be created when you deploy. In other words: you don't need to create the pod(s) yourself, the deployment will do it for you for the number of asked replica.

Comment: you do not need a separate file for pod, put that pod definition in the deployment and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The error you encountered is because, in your Deployment definition, you didn't specify a container. In a Deployment, you should define a template for the Pods it creates. The template includes the Pod's specifications, including its container(s). This separation allows Deployments to control the creation and scaling of Pods based on the desired state you specify.

Here's how you should modify your Deployment to include the container:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: site-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: site-deploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: site-deploy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: site-pod
        image: guirms/website-k8s-frontend:1.1
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 4200
```

In this modified Deployment, you specify the container definition within the spec.template.spec.containers section. This is necessary for the Deployment to create and manage Pods correctly.

While it may seem redundant to define the container again, it provides the flexibility to change the container image or configuration at the Deployment level. This is especially useful when you want to perform updates or rollbacks across multiple Pods. In practice, Deployments are a powerful tool for managing the lifecycle of your application in a Kubernetes cluster.